# Can I turn off all "Notification" of all apps, services in Android phone?

Tags: notifications, battery, battery-life, sony-xperia-z

I found tips to improve battery in this link: http://www.gottabemobile.com/2012/10/30/hurricane-sandy-crisis-map-puts-shelters-storm-info-alerts-power-outages-on-mobile/

In this link - author said we can turn off Notification of android/iOS applications to save battery.

I have an Android phone. If I go to Settings/ Personalization / Manage Notifications (Sony Xperia). I will see all Applications/ Android Services that I can turn off notifications

**My questions is CAN I turn off all application notifications (downloaded / built-in apps) / android service notifications (app services/built-in services)?** If I turn off all of them - Does this affect operation of the phone? I understand that I will not receive any notifications (news/updates ... ) if I turn off notifications. I can check updates manually.

Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the Android version running on the device, that might be possible. Taking a raw (and optimistic) guess, this might gain you 2 minutes more battery endurance (if at all). Do you really think that's worth it? There are much better things you can do to increase battery-life, many of them linked from our [battery-life tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery-life/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can turn off all notifications.  Your phone will work fine, but you will not receive any notifications, which will severely limit functionality of applications that depend on notifications to alert you of events and progress.

Furthermore, the amount of battery life saved by doing this will be so close to zero, that I honestly can't recommend it.

Disable notifications for annoying apps.  Leave them on for others.

Comment: @LocHa You're welcome!  If you found it helpful, you can click the up arrow to apply an upvote!  :-)